# moving from development to production

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

**BACKGROUND**

I'm developing a web application on Visual Studio using mssql-server express and was hoping for a little guidance.

I'd like to put this web application in a real world environment and access it through the internet for testing purposes.  I'm asking this question for two reasons:

1. I'd like to know the difference in speed between the localhost and a production environment.
2. A cost overview of bringing a web application into a production environment.

**QUESTION:**

Could you provide me with a general overview of how to make this happen and the costs associated with each step?
Suggestions of books or other resources on this topic would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why don't you test it in your localhost??? Is there a reason? Normally, we don't publish an application for testing purposes...

Comment: I guess the main purpose is for testing the speed.  I'd like to know the difference in speed between using the localhost and the production environment.

Comment: Ok. You should put it in your question to be more clear...

Comment: Localhost = one user/you vs. Production = x users. Desktop machine vs. Server OS. Shared hosting and/or db vs dedicated vs "cloud". See [WCAT](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86) for testing on IIS (free).

Answer (score 0):

In order to test for performance reasons, I would suggest to use a **cloud virtual machine**. There you could change your vm's available resources dynamically in order to check it's availability and overall behaviour under various vm resource configurations. The reason I suggest using a cloud VM and not a cloud hosting service, is that in your VM you would have more freedom to make adjustments which could affect performance (database setups etc).

One of the most popular cloud services for virtual machines is the [Amazon Elastic Cloud platform](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). Since you use the Microsoft development ecosystem, you should also consider using the [Microsoft Azure platform](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) which would have better integration with your tools (visual studio). Regarding prices, you could check the [Amazon EC pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) and the [Microsoft Azure price calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines). Both of these services have free trial packages and very flexible plans to minimize your costs.

Hope I helped!